# How I can solve the VBA Projects to work in MS Office?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

All VBA projects fail to work, if you use Excel, the VBA project deleted when trying to open the workbook, if it is Access, no application works because it does not find any project.

For what I've had been researched and tested, apparently the reason is the Windows 10 update, I focused exclusively on the Office 2010, seeing macros, security, library references etc, but it seems that Windows is the problem and not the Office itself. This problem appeared 3 days ago, before that everything worked fine.

I would appreciate your help if someone else had the same problem and how you solve it.

I have Windows 10 Home, and I tried with Office 2010 (my original base Office) and then I install Office 2016 hoping to solve it, but nothing works.
Thank you very much in advance.

- uninstall and install again Office 2010 with all the features (including VBA).
- Macro security fully enabled
- VBAProject references ok
- Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications install correctly.
- Install Office 2016, to try if the problem solved
- Reinstall Windows 10 Home 64 to the factory line.

Comment: The antivirus removes everything?

Comment: Kaspersky is my antivirus, I am open tu hear o read some probable solutions. What to you advice me to do?

Comment: Hello, it would be very important for me if any one know how to solve this problem, but unfortunately no one respond. I asume this page is active, right?